# PHP - Get the value by key in a multi-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimension array like:

```
$fields = 
    Array (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [field_special_features5_value] => Special Function 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [field_special_features6_value] => Special Function 6
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [field_opticalzoom_value] => Optical Zoom
            )
    )
```

I want to get the value by key, I tried the code below but not work

```
$tmp = array_search('field_special_features5_value' , $fields);
echo $tmp;
```

How can I get the value `Special Function 5` of the key `field_special_features5_value`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print $fields[1]['field_special_features5_value'];`

or if you don't know at which index your array is, something like this:

```
function GetKey($key, $search)
{
    foreach ($search as $array)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $array))
        {
            return $array[$key];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$tmp = GetKey('field_special_features5_value' , $fields);
echo $tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know where it is located in the `$fields` array, try :

```
$value = $fields[1]['field_special_features5_value'];
```

If not, try :

```
function getSubkey($key,$inArray)
{
    for ($fields as $field)
    {
         $keys = array_keys($field);
         if (isset($keys[$key])) return $keys[$key];
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

And use it like this :

```
<?php
     $value = getSubkey("field_special_features5_value",$fields);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to search recursive:

```
function array_search_recursive(array $array, $key) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            if($found = array_search_recursive($v, $key)){
                return $found;
            }
        } elseif ($k == $key) {
             return $v;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    }
}

$result = array_search_recursive($fields, 'field_special_features5_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a top-level index first before you can search you array. So to access that value you need to do this:

```
$tmp = $fields[1]['field_special_features5_value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with recursive function like this

```
<?php

function multi_array_key_exists($needle, $haystack) {
       foreach ($haystack as $key=>$value) {
         if ($needle===$key) {
           return $key;
         }
         if (is_array($value)) {
           if(multi_array_key_exists($needle, $value)) {
             return multi_array_key_exists($needle, $value);
           }
         }
       }
   return false;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Well, this could work... but why use recursion when in fact the original post implies that the OP knows that the array is NOT actually representing a tree-like structure with an unknown number of 'branches', but a 2-dimensional one...?